# Can you help me understand Derek Parfit's thought experiment?

Tags: rationality, hedonism, philosophy-of-psychology

[image]

This is an excerpt from Parfit's Reasons and Persons. I can't totally wrap my head around it. Of course, I get the basic idea: Kate is a writer who works too hard. Her work makes her happy. But she works too hard and sometimes gets depressed as a result.
Why can Kate not work just a little bit less hard? There seems to be an underlying mechanistic psychology here, in which desires *cause* us to act, rather than reasons. It seems that Parfit is saying, "Look, the Hedonistic theory is self-defeating because when someone is very irrational, bad sh*t happens." Wait, what?

Comment: similar argumnents can be used to claim that *reasons* lead to similar self-defeating scenarios, so what gives?

Comment: I’m not sure that’s true. Replace desire with reason and the situation becomes “Kate’s strongest reason is that her books be as good as possible.” In this case how could it be irrational for her to act accordingly?

Comment: @BenjaminGrange To reason logically about anything, you need first to be clear about the terms. There is an obvious conflict between self-interest and pleasure. It is nobody's self-interest to be addicted to anything. So, the would-be philosopher reason about the Hedonistic Theory would first need to clarify their concepts. The fallacy of this sort of arguments is in the fluffiness of the concepts assumed.

Comment: @BenjaminGrange "rational" or not can equally fail to bring about happiness, this is the point I tried to make.

Comment: @BenjaminGrange for example many things have thresholds of activation. Maybe getting less satisfaction (below threshold) daily is useless, so prefering to get the right amount (above threshold) but tolerate lapses instead. So you see where the argument can fail..

Comment: Your effort of thinking brought food to contemplate. Epicurus's hedonistic theory is sense based of which the correct application requires the acceptance of the *fundamental truth* of the things a person perceives. It's not uncommon truly great piece of work needs hard labor and necessarily creator's depression most times. Actually Epicurus advocates a life of hedonistic moderation by reducing desire, thus eliminating the unhappiness caused by unfulfilled desires. And he advocates shun away from the worse vain desires including desires for power, wealth, and fame inculcated by false beliefs...

Comment: However, having said above, it doesn't necessarily mean Parfit's critique is without merit. The *real* trick here for Hedonism is the acceptance of the fundamental truth of the things a person perceives, and most people cannot clearly judge what's the fundamental truth even from their seemingly natural and easy everyday mundane perceptions, so in your above quote if her desire is ultimately fame and money, then she'll be the typical example described above. Had she have the *right* desire, she may not get depressed even she worked extremely hard. The magic is find the *fundamental truth*...

Comment: "*Discretion is the better part of valor.*" And: "*Why should you destroy yourself?*" (Ecclesiastes) It is a pretty old question, with an equally old answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that Parfit's argument seems to require the assumption "If Kate's strongest desire is to write, then she overworks, making her sometimes self-denying." Then the contrapositive is that if Kate is never self-denying, her strongest desire is not the desire to write, so she finds her work boring, which is much worse for her than the depression she would've faced if her strongest desire was to write. So you are correct in claiming that there is an assumption that Kate's desire could *cause* her to act in a certain way that is worse for her.

In fact if you read a little further, you will find Parfit's discussion of precisely this objection. The objection, clearly stated: if Kate's desire to write causes her to overwork, then working this amount is not self-denying, because working the correct amount is not one of the acts that are possible for her to do. Kate is self-denying only if she performs an act that is worse for her than another act that it is possible for her to do. On the other hand, if Kate's desire to write does not "force" her to overwork, then the assumption stated at the beginning does not hold, and we cannot conclude that it would be worse for Kate if she were never self-denying. (Because it is no longer true that "never self-denying" implies "strongest desire is not the desire to write").

Parfit wants the example to appeal to people who believe Kate could be forced to act in a certain way by her desire, and to people who do not. To the first group, he claims that Kate is forced to overwork by her desire to write, but simultaneously, she *can* choose to work less (if only she had different desires). In other words, he puts forward an understanding of the word "can" under which Kate truly does violate S by overworking.

To the second group, he basically claims that when her strongest desire is to write, she can, on any individual occasion, choose not to overwork. But she cannot constantly choose not to overwork. It does not require psychological determinism to claim that Kate will, at *some point*, do something, if you stipulate she can freely choose when to do it. This part is weird and open to interpretation; I'd recommend reading the entire section yourself.
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think the answer is fine, but maybe I am irrational.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. But thank you. I think you're right that time might be relevant here. That overall she wants her life to be one filled with writing, but in actuality, when she writes she just feels tired. Well, maybe she shouldn't actually be a writer! If it saps her energy, maybe it's not really her calling. It's impossible for me to understand this without positing some serious cognitive dissonance and lack of self-understanding on Kate's part. Maybe that's what Parfit is trying to elucidate here. It is a part of the human condition.